# fetching form value in an array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have this dynamically populated form fields.

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
```

on jQuery's keyup i want to fetch all the value from `input[name="quantity[]"]` and perform some calculations like total quantity i.e something like

```
(field1 quantity value) + (field2 quantity value) + (field3 quantity value) ... n
```

i tried fetching the value like this.

```
$('input[name="quantity[]"]').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
});
```

this only fetches the value of first element and ignores the rest of fields. how do i go with what i want?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity"/>

<input type="text" name="res" placeholder="Resultado"/>



$(document).ready(function() {


$('input[name="quantity[]"]').keyup(function(){
   var val = 0;
   $('input[name="quantity[]"]').each(function() {
                val += Number($(this).val());
            });
    $('input[name="res"]').val(val);
});
```

});

fuente con jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kSw4G/3/

by JNE

Answer (score 2):

```
var $quantity = $('input[name="quantity[]"]');

$quantity.keyup(function(){
    var val = 0;
    $quantity.each(function(){
        val += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
});
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, what is the use of second argument in parseInt()?

Comment: Just to insure that you are adding numeric values rather than concatenating strings.  The + operator does double duty in JavaScript, and .val() returns a string.  It is necessary to convert this to a numeric value if you want to math operations.

Comment: does not work for the second field, this only fetches the value from first field

Answer (score 1):

```
var ref = $('input[name^="quantity"]');
    ref.keyup(function(e){
        var result = 0;
        ref.each(function() {
          console.log($(this).val());
          if($(this).val().length && $(this).val() != '') {
            result += parseInt($(this).val());
          }
          console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YBQKz/)**

Comment: since the value is being fetched as string i am getting an error `NaN`, how do i force jQuery to treat it as integer?

Comment: noticed that parstInt already does that. then how come i am getting NAN error

Comment: you can do it like this if(val == ""){result += 0}else{result += parseInt(val);}

Comment: this have some logical error. if i change the field value then it will keep appending from the last value it fetched. for example if i have value of 100 in field 1 and then if i change it to 200 it will result in 300

Comment: still the calculation does not come proper

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar see the demo

Comment: actually the problem was with using `this` keyword, since i needed to reinitialize the value on every keyup. and rightly pointed out by @Iori Yagami, his solution worked well.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to assign each text box a class let suppose quantity then

```
var total_quantity = 0;  
$('.quantity').keyup(function()
{
    $(this).each(function()
    {
        total_quantity += $(this).val();
    });
});
```